# Interpolating timeseries in MATLAB to find the time for a specific value, then looking this time up in another timeseries

Tags: matlab

I have a timeseries that outputs data (`time` vs `theta`) from a Simulink model into the MATLAB workspace. I want to automatically interpolate this data so I can find what time (`t1`) it would be when `theta == 45`.

I then need to look up `t1` in another time series (`time` vs `velocity`) and then output what the velocity would be at that time.

How can I do this? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

EDIT: I can interpolate the first timeseries with a new time vector and finer resolution so it has `theta == 45` exactly, but my method is pretty brute force and requires manually looking at the time series first to determine what times I need to interpolate between (else it would take forever) which I'd like to avoid, e.g:

```
theta2 = resample(theta, 1.68:0.0000001:1.685)
```

Comment: I suppose there is no analytic function available for `theta(t)`. You could try a [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) (or even a more involved root finding algorithm like Brent's method). You can easily implement this yourself or find an implementation somewhere online.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `theta` and `velocity` are timeseries objects.

You can search the time interval `[time_start, time_finish]` as follows. However, this assumes that you know that there is a sign change in this interval.

```
t1 = fzero(@(t) theta.resample(t).Data - 45, [time_start, time_finish]);
```

Then, given `t1`, you can interpolate the velocity directly.

```
vel = velocity.resample(t1).Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections) from the File Exchange to find the intersection of your timeseries and a straight line at `theta = 45`:

```
% assume t and theta exist in the base workspace
theta_45 = 45*ones(size(theta));
[t1,theta1] = intersections(t,theta,t,theta_45); % t1 and theta1 are column vectors of the intersection points
```

Then take say the first element of `t1` and look it up in your second time vector `t2` (I assume `t2` is monotonically increasing so that should be straightforward) and find the corresponding index `idx2`. `velocity(idx2)` is your desired value.